# Template: Determine template arguments by function prototype

Tags: c++, templates

I have the function pointer type or function prototype:

```
int function (int arg);
typedef int (*function_t) (int arg);
```

and template class like

```
template <typename T_ret, typename... T_args> 
class caller {
    T_ret (*m_p) (T_args... args);
public:
    T_ret call (T_args... args) {
        return m_p(args);
    }
    caller (T_ret (*p)(T_args...args)) : m_p(p) {}
};
```

Is it possible to make compiler automatically determine template parameters within code like

```
class caller2 : public caller <__something_with_function_prototype__> {
    caller2 : caller (function) {};
};
```

And similar question: is it possible to do this but with another template class instead of function?

```
template <typename T_ret, typename... T_args> class example;
typedef example<int, int> example_t;
```

Thank you.

Comment: The solution is [here](http://ideone.com/TxYh3X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but maybe:

```
#include <iostream>

int function (int arg) { return arg; }
typedef int (*function_t) (int arg);

template <typename T_ret, typename... T_args> 
class caller {
    T_ret (*m_p) (T_args... args);
public:
    T_ret call (T_args... args) {
        return m_p(args...);
    }
    caller (T_ret (*p)(T_args...args)) : m_p(p) {}
};

template <typename T_ret, typename... T_args>
caller<T_ret, T_args...> get_caller(T_ret(*prototype)(T_args...))
{
    return caller<T_ret, T_args...>(prototype);
}

int main()
{
    function_t f = &function;
    auto c = get_caller(f);
    std::cout << c.call(1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo link.](http://ideone.com/zuYl3p)

OR maybe:

```
#include <iostream>

int function (int arg) { return arg; }
typedef int (*function_t) (int arg);

template <typename T> 
class caller {};

template <typename T_ret, typename... T_args> 
class caller<T_ret(*)(T_args...)> {
    T_ret (*m_p) (T_args... args);
public:
    T_ret call (T_args... args) {
        return m_p(args...);
    }
    caller (T_ret (*p)(T_args...args)) : m_p(p) {}
};

int main()
{
    caller<decltype(&function)> c(&function);
    std::cout << c.call(1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Yet another live demo link.](http://ideone.com/eUFdWA)

Comment: The second is what I need, but I have to redefine my template class for using with function and with another template class. I'm already have two definitions: for general T_ret and for T_ret = void. Can I avoid this complexities somehow?

Comment: @Pirot: absolutely. Now I have two such definitions. And I have to add another two, if I want to use it like `caller<example<int, void> >`. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @shved: you want to use `caller<decltype(&function)>` to be expanded as `caller<example<int, void>>` ?

Comment: So, with your and @Jarod42 help, I resolve this issue like [this](http://ideone.com/TxYh3X). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use some helper:

```
template <typename F> struct helper;

template <typename T_ret, typename... T_args>
struct helper<T_ret (*) (T_args... args)>
{
    using type = caller<T_ret, T_args...>;
};
```

And then use it like

```
int function (int arg);

class caller2 : public helper<decltype(&function)>::type {
public:
    caller2() : caller (&function) {}
};
```

And to be more generic:

```
template <typename T_ret, typename... T_args>
struct helper<T_ret (*) (T_args... args)>
{
    template <template <typename, typename...> class C>
    using type = C<T_ret, T_args...>;
};
```

And then

```
class caller2 : public helper<decltype(&function)>::type<caller> {
public:
    caller2() : caller (&function) {}
};
```

and so `helper<decltype(&function)>::type<example>` is `example<int, int>`

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly and it solve the problem, but the using code became more complex.

Comment: BTW, you may use `function_t` instead of `decltype(&function)` as they are the same type.

Comment: So, with your and @Piotr help, I resolve this issue like [this](http://ideone.com/TxYh3X). Thank you.

Comment: @shved: Your specialization for `void` is useless (same as general case).